# How to iterate though @RequestParam in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm building an API in Spring and I have a quick question:

I want to perform checks on these parameters below to see whether they contain values, before carrying out some logic on them.

I'm new to Spring - is there anyway to do "get" out these values into some sort of data structure so I can perform my checks?

```
        @RequestParam(value = "video") MultipartFile video,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureOne") MultipartFile pictureOne,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureTwo") MultipartFile pictureTwo,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureThree") MultipartFile pictureThree,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureFour", required = false) MultipartFile pictureFour,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureFive", required = false) MultipartFile pictureFive,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureSix",  required = false) MultipartFile pictureSix,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureSeven", required = false) MultipartFile pictureSeven,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureEight", required = false) MultipartFile pictureEight,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureNine", required = false) MultipartFile pictureNine,
        @RequestParam(value = "pictureTen", required = false) MultipartFile pictureTen)
```

Comment: I would start by questioning your basic approach--why are you using form upload for eleven files simultaneously?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a better solution might be to send the pictures over as an array. Something like this: `@RequestParam(value="pictures[]") MultipartFile[] pictures`

Comment: If nothing else, create an array: `for (MultipartFile file : new MultipartFile[] { video, pictureOne, pictureTwo, pictureThree, pictureFour, pictureFive, pictureSix, pictureSeven, pictureEight, pictureNine, pictureTen }) { /* code here */ }`. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for this - managed to get it working following @mbridges's approach. Much cleaner code! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform validation for all this values and close it in structure I recommend to create DTO object and put all variables as fields, ex:

```
public class FilesDto{
    private MultipartFile video;
    private MultipartFile photos[];
}
//Getters setters...
```

Then in your Controller

```
@Autowired
private SomeValidator someValidator;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void savePhotos(@Valid FilesDto filesDto) {
    ....
}

@InitBinder("filesDto")
protected void initBinde(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(someValidator);
}
```

Where `someValidator` is class that implements `Validator` interface.
According to @mbridges in comment, I also strongly recommend to use array instead of listing all parameters.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for this - managed to get it working following @mbridges's approach. Much cleaner code! Thanks for your help.